# How to store package repository globally?

Tags: cabal, cabal-install

A FreeBSD update forces me to run Xmonad by cabal-install. After I run "cabal new-update"
 I find that it audaciously placed a 636MB file inside the directory "~/.cabal". Having a closer look I noticed that this is the unzipped version of a .tar.gz of 85MB.

Question #1: How can I inhibit to unpack this monster?

Question #2: I am loggin in as two different users. Is there a way to install the zipfile in a global place?

Thanks in advance,
Bertram

Comment: I made ~/.cabal a symlink to an unencrypted partition with enough free space.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inhibit the unpacking of it. Cabal needs it to operate. That said, your solution to how to replace it with a symlink seems fine.